# Software to monitor desktop computers on a LAN

Tags: remote-desktop, display, administration

Do you know of a software where it can 'broadcast' the activities of a particular user? Kind of like VNC but the viewing administrator can view multiple users, possibly in separate windows??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to as many computers as you want over VNC and simultaneously ...

A few years ago I used RAdmin for this kind of activity (http://www.radmin.com/). It's commercial, but it's pretty good, at leas it was in the time of Windows 2000/XP. They have a 30 days trial/demo, so you can try it out.

If you want a centralized hardware/software monitoring solution, and not to see what others do and spy on their screen, you may be interested in Zabbix (http://www.zabbix.com/)